# Setting System Wide Variables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-view

I'm interested in finding a method where a system wide variable can be written onto the Snowflake Account, and used in a view so that users can see the underlying DDL, but not know the value used in a particular function.

At the moment this is done by making these a "Secure" View, but that limits almost everyone from seeing the underlying DDL (which would be helpful to our users and admins).

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a System Wide Variable, and use that in the DDL.

Example:

```
    SET SYSTEM VARIABLE variable_name = 'some_value';

    CREATE VIEW catalog.schema.tablename AS
        SELECT TRANSLATE(COLUMN_NAME, '0123456789', variable_name) AS NEW_COLUMN_NAME
        FROM <FULL SOURCE TABLE NAME>
        WHERE <WHATEVER CONDITIONS APPLY>;
```

I have found setting variables on a session, and I know I can see / change Account Parameters.  But can I create something like Account Variables?

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function [has two privileges on it](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#other-database-object-privileges-sequences-udfs) - OWNERSHIP and USAGE. If you don't give either of these function privileges to the viewer of the view, but you give the viewer SELECT privileges on the view, they will be able to see the DDL of the view, but won't be able to see the details of the UDF. Then you can store values in your UDF that you don't want other people seeing. I'll post code for this in just a second.

```sql
--Something like this to test it out from scratch. You must have accountadmin for this to work:
--use role accountadmin:
--create a database called demo_db;
--create a role called owner_demo_db and grant it usage, monitor, and create schema; also give it usage on a warehouse;
--create a user called demo_db_user. give them ownership on demo_db;
--create a role called reader_demo_db;
--assign the "reader" and the "owner" role to demo_db_user;
--as the owner_demo_db role, create the following: 



use role owner_demo_db;

--The role owner_demo_db will own this function
create function pi_udf()
  returns float
  as '3.141592654::FLOAT'
;

--The role owner_demo_db will own this view
create view MyView as
select 'some_value' AS someval
    , pi_udf() pi_val;

--Because owner_demo_db owns the view, they can grant select to the reader role to the view
grant select on view demo_db.demo_schema.MyView to reader_demo_db;

--Show functions and views and you'll be able to see both.
show functions;
show views;

--Show functions and views as reader_demo_db, and you'll only be able to see DDL for the view b/c you don't have a privilege on the function
use role reader_demo_db;
show functions;
show views;
```